# Authorization openAM vs LDAP vs AD

Tags: openam

I am new to this terms.
So can anyone explain which is better for implementing authorization ?

Please also explain reason for the same.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your usages - but you seem a tad confused.

OpenAM is an open source Authentication, Authorization, Web SSO & Federation solution. OpenAM embeds OpenDJ which is what you'd be referring to however it can utilise other LDAP directory servers or can use OpenDJ Externally (which it is tailored for).

LDAP is a protocol used for accessing a directory. A directory contains  objects; generally these objects are related to users, groups, and other things within the organisation.

OpenDJ & Active Directory are both Directory Servers. These differ from the LDAP protocol.

If you are looking for pros and cons of directory servers alongside a length definition i suggest a search of Stack Overflow for an already written answer on this topic or reading here:

https://www.ldap.com/choosing-an-ldap-server